# Converting .msg files to .xps format?

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, xps

My application converts Microsoft Office documents into .XPS files.

I've successfully used Office Interop to convert Word, Excel and PowerPoint files. I can't figure out how to do the same for "Outlook Message Format (.msg)" files.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is Microsoft.Office.Interop, question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would [first convert the **MSG** to **DOC**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210279%28v=office.11%29.aspx), **HTML**, or **MHTML** and then do a [secondary conversion to 
**XPS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb412305%28v=office.12%29.aspx). There is no direct conversion support from **MSG** to **XPS** from within Outlook interop.

```
mailItem.SaveAs(targetDoc, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olDoc); // convert MSG to DOC
// convert DOC as XPS
var wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(targetDoc);
if (wordDocument != null)
    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetXPS, 
        Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS, paramOpenAfterExport, paramExportOptimizeFor,
        paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage,
        paramEndPage, paramExportItem, paramIncludeDocProps, 
        paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks, paramDocStructureTags, 
        paramBitmapMissingFonts, paramUseISO19005_1,
        ref paramMissing);
```